# Ionic 4 (Angular 7) 'default history' equivalent for deep linking?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, deep-linking, ionic4

I am learning Ionic 4 further and trying to find equivalent for "default history" with Angular 7's routing approach.

In Ionic 3 there was "default history" property as part of IonicPage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/IonicPage/

This would allow a use case such as:

- user navigates to www.mywebsite.com/**list/detail/99**
- now user clicks "back" button and gets to www.mywebsite.com/**list** even tough they never visited **list** prior and went directly to the detail page.

Code wise in Ionic 3 we would use "defaultHistory":

```
...
@IonicPage({
  name: 'detail-page',
  segment: 'detail/:id',
  defaultHistory: ['list']
})
...
```

Now in Ionic 4 / Angular 7 (which uses Angular's router now) I struggle to find equivalent method.

I understand what I could in theory achieve something similar using web apis (such as [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)) but is there Angular 7 way?

**UPDATE1:**

I checked that ion-back-button does have defaultHref which can accept a route string. But issue is that this button (back-button) won't really show itself if the browsing history is empty...

Comment: in back button `this.router.navigate(["/list"], {replaceUrl:true});` or `this.location.replaceState('/list');` something like this maybe ?

Comment: Potentially, I see this one prop: defaultHref and think it might be it? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button#properties like on detail page I should (I guess) use it and point it at the list component related route. But I need to validate this with code

Comment: @SouravDutta so the issue with your proposed path is that in Ionic 4 the back-button is not rendered if there is no browsing history. So one of the problems is that if I click a deep link URL that leads me to "list/detail" - the back button won't be there;/